# Amount of derivative zeroes between adjacent roots of a polynomial - cleaner proof

Tags: calculus, polynomials

I'm trying to prove the following theorem: "Between two adjacent roots $a, b$ of a polynomial $p(x)$ there is always an odd number of zeroes of $p'$, with multiplicity being accounted for".

Now, this is pretty intuitive to visualize as the values of $p'$ at $a$ and $b$ need to have opposite signs, so that $p'$ has to change signs an even number of times and each time $p'$ changes signs is a root of $p'$ with odd multiplicity, while all other roots, so those where $p'$ keeps its sign, have to have even multiplicity and hence don't change the parity of the number of zeroes of $p'$ in $(a, b)$.

While this does make for a working proof, I find it to include a lot of "continuous" argumentation and some points which would need to be treated very carefully for the proof to be logically sound which feels unclean to me for this sort of problem. I feel like there should exist a cleaner and more discrete approach to this since we're dealing with polynomials, but so far I was unable to find one.

I thought about using Rolle's theorem to find one root $z$ of $p'$ and shifting the function downward to again apply Rolle's theorem, this time with $z$ as one of the endpoints, maybe together with some sort of inductive approach. I have also considered using the factoring of $p$ or $p'$ but I haven't gotten anywhere yet.

Comment: Hmm. If $p$ has a multiple root at $a$, $b$, or both, then it seems hard to talk about $p'$ having "opposite" signs at $a$ and $b$—if $p'(a)=0$ or $p'(b)=0$. I would be inclined to argue that $p$ is increasing or decreasing except on a finite set, the roots of $p'$; the "direction" of $p$ switches when $p'$ has a root of odd multiplicity and stays the same for roots of even multiplicity; and $p'$ has "opposite direction" to the right of $a$ and to the left of $b$, assuming $a<b$ and there are no roots of $p$ between $a$ and $b$. (This isn't a huge deal: just talking about the values of...

Comment: ... $p'$ at $a+\epsilon$ and $b-\epsilon$, instead of at $a$ and $b$ precisely.)